# Телеграм бот с кнопкой request_poll на PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Хочу создавать кнопку с `request_poll` но мне не получилось

На документацию телеграму не понял там написанно тип `keyboardbuttonpolltype`. А другие `request_contact` и `request_location` написанно `boolean` ну это понятно.
Но "**keyboardbuttonpolltype**" этого не понял.

Попробовал так:

```
  'keyboard' => array(
    array(
     array( 
      'text'=>"Poll",
        'request_poll'=>'quiz'))),
       'resize_keyboard' => true)
));

А где ошибка здесь?

Жмаю кнопку а реакция нет. Запрос как только простой текстовая кнопка.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  'keyboard' => array(
    array(
     array( 
      'text'=>"Poll",
        'request_poll'=>'(['type'=>'quiz']))),
       'resize_keyboard' => true)
));
```